# Rebuilding Indexes in Postgresql running on AWS Aurora Serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, indexing, aws-aurora-serverless

I am using PostgreSQL on AWS Aurora Serverless and have created few indexes on the table. So do we need to rebuild those indexes or run any stats after each data load to keep them updated for its done automatically in AWS Aurora Serverless. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The indexes will update automatically after any new data is loaded or updated.

> indexes in PostgreSQL do not need maintenance or tuning

Here is the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-examine.html) regarding analyzing indexes.

Comment: Thanks. But the size of my index is around 1300 MB. Also if indexes in PostgreSQL do not require any maintenance then what is the use of REINDEX command in PostgreSQL.

Comment: @abc there are only certain circumstances where reindexing is necessary: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/sql-reindex.html